# How can I make the expand/collapse triangles bigger?

Tags: treeview, kendo-ui

Kendo UI treeview triangles are too tiny for my users.
I want to make them bigger.

Answer (score 4):

If those are the only icons that you want to make bigger, you can try creating two images with the desired size and then define the following styles:

```
#grid .k-hierarchy-cell > .k-icon.k-plus {
    background-image: url('/images/plus.png');
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

#grid .k-hierarchy-cell > .k-icon.k-minus {
    background-image: url('/images/minus.png');
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Here I create an image and saved in `/images/plus.png` for expanding the details and size 32x32 pixels and another saved in `/images/minus.png` for collapsing it.

With the CSS selector I'm limiting its scope to a grid which `id` is `grid`.

Comment: Thanks OnaBia! Having a CSS selector of just 
.k-icon.k-minus 
worked for me.
Also a pixel size of 16 x 16 was also still much bigger than the default but provided enough of an increase in size.

Comment: Watch out not narrowing CSS selector since same `.k-icon.k-minus` might be used in other situations and you might change it also. It uses to be better to be too _aggressive_ since we don't control everyplace where it might be used.

Comment: I'm glad that your problem is solved. Don't forget to accept the answer letting others know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually edit 'Default/sprite.png' located in you styles folder together with other kendo styles. This post should get you started >> http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/general-discussions/using-the-kendo-ui-theme-builder.aspx#Bi_T-0dZtEuYNyT-ypDIlA , use attached *x2.psd sprites or edit files further in photoshop.